# How can I write a loop to set the value of sum[i] and delete datatable columns where sum[i] <= 0

Tags: c#

```
int i = 0;
string[] sum = new string[256];

for (i = 1; i < 256; i++)
{
    sum[i] = sum[i].ToString();
    sum[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("Sum(BIN" + i.ToString() + ")", string.Empty));

    if(sum[i] == 0)
    {
        dt.Columns.Remove("BIN"+i.ToString()+"");
    }
}
```

Comment: Line 7 overwrites the effect of line 6. Please make very clear what the intended result should be.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++) { if (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute($"Sum(BIN{i})", string.Empty)) <= 0) dt.Columns.Remove($"BIN{i}"); }` seems like it accurately translates what you're trying to do. Not sure if that works or not, though.

Comment: you're welcome. did it work?

Comment: Yes,I change string to int and delete line 5 as you suggest @RufusL

Comment: Ok thanh you,@RufusL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem where you're trying to assign an `int` to `sum[i]`, because `sum` is a `string[]`, and you can't assign an `int` to one of the items.

Instead, it seems you want to get the return value from the method and save it in a variable so you can compare it. In order to do this, we can modify the code like:

```
string[] sum = new string[256];

for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
{
    int result = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("Sum(BIN" + i.ToString() + ")", string.Empty));

    if (result <= 0)
    {
        dt.Columns.Remove("BIN" + i.ToString() + "");
    }
}
```

This can be simplified further by using the return value of the method directly in the `if` condition. We can also use interpolated strings instead of concatenation:

```
string[] sum = new string[256];

for (i = 1; i < sum.Length; i++)
{
    if(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute($"Sum(BIN{i})", string.Empty)) <= 0)
    {
        dt.Columns.Remove($"BIN{i}");
    }
}
```